# The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value

Tags: powerbi

i was calculating waiting time <60 sec in power bi but i am getting an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzU2b.png)

can anyone help to get through this

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, you may want to read the how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask also add more around is the a column or measure, and add some dummy data so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: You may also try wrapping the statement with a calculate, and aggregation, smux, AVG etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you try to assign the outcome of a filter (what is a table, to a variable)

You are saying: I was calculating.. What does this mean? Is is that you want to count them or do you want to have a true/false for each row?

To help you going, you can add a column and get the count by:

```
WaitMore60Sec = Calculate(COUNT('Phone Call Data'[waiting tym]), FILTER('Phone Call Data', 'Phone Call Data'[waiting tym]) < TIME(0,1,0)))
```

You can get true/false by:

```
WaitMore60Sec = 'Phone Call Data'[waiting tym]) < TIME(0,1,0)
```